# ng-click not binding checked or unchecked event properly for a checkbox in ui-grid, always taking it as false?

Tags: jquery, iphone

ui-grid is as below

```
$scope.grid = {
                gridApi: {},
                data: [],
                subgrid: 'false',
                columnDefs: [
                      {
                          field: "incidentWith", name: "Incident With", width: "10%", enableHiding: false,
                          cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" id={{row.entity.FlightCrewId}} ng-click="grid.appScope.fnEvrChkClick(this)"/>'
                      }
                ]
            };
```

My code is as below

```
    $scope.fnEvrChkClick = function (obj) {
// when checke box is checked then
// The below condition is true in Desktop view in Chrome Debugger 
// and false in iphone 6 view
                if ($("#" + obj.row.entity.FlightCrewId).is(":checked")) 
                   // This is the code executed when checkbox is checked 
                   //    and the chrome debugger is in Desktop mode
                 else
                       // This is the code executed when checkbox is  
                       // checked and the chrome debugger is in iPhone 6 mode
                }
```

When checkbox is checked, then 
In Debugger, when my application is in Desktop mode the following code is true which is correct as shown below . 
[image]

But when the same is in IPHONE 6 view, it gives me false.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve this by using **ng-change** instead of **ng-click** in my grid cellTemplate as below and binding it to **ng-model**

```
   {field: "incidentWith", name: "Incident With", width: "10%", enableHiding: false,   
cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.seletedValue"
 id={{row.entity.FlightCrewId}} ng-change="grid.appScope.fnEvrChkClick(this)"/>'}
```

And in my function i was always checking the seletedValue

```
// Now in iphone view of Chrome Debugger
$scope.fnEvrChkClick = function (obj) {
 if (obj.seletedValue) 
  // this line is executed if true
  else
  // this line is executed if false
}
```